# Extract ladder logics from text file into Python

Tags: python, verification, plc

I have ladder logic generated from a logic design tool and it's something like this:

**ladder logic**

[image]

Is there a way I can extract ladder logic from text file into Python code or maybe verilog code? and do some simulation/testing with it? if so .. how?

Comment: Welcome. I'm sure that it is possible and you've done something before posting this question. Could you share you efforts with us?

Comment: I have been googling around for many days looking for any exiting packages, but haven't found anything useful. I have no idea how to go about his at all. I have heard that it is possible to convert plc logic like this to verilog, not sure how it can be done.